# Salesforce Web To Lead form storing strange data

Tags: data, person-accounts, web2lead

I have some web to lead forms with a hard coded firstname and lastname, the records in Salesforce itself seem to randomly either be correctly showing the hard-coded fields or showing a random string such as `5c375c95c90d2` - all the web to lead form accounts should show the same "Firstname Lastname" for example, as this is simply a newsletter sign up prospect list.

What would cause the data to come through as the above from Salesforce's end, if anything?

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="form subscribe" id="salesforce-signup-form" target="hiddeniFrame">

    <input type="hidden" id="###" name="###" value="UK">

    <input type="hidden" id="###" name="###" value="Sign Up">

    <input type="hidden" id="###" title="Channel" name="###" value="Direct">

    <input type="hidden" id="lead_source" name="lead_source" value="Web">

    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="hidden" value="Firstname">

    <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="hidden" value="Lastname">

    <input type="hidden" id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" value="###"><br>

    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address..." maxlength="80">

    <button class="action subscribe primary inactive" title="Submit" type="submit">
        <span>Submit</span>
    </button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="###" class="checkbox" id="###" value="1">

</form>
```

Comment: Hello @aravona - welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Are you able to edit your post and include the Web2Lead form code that you have on your website. This will help people with trying to assist you.

Comment: @developer__c - sure I can put an anonymised form in would that help? It's from a live site.